# Blackberry Messenger SDK apps don't show up in sim

Tags: blackberry, java-me, sdk

1. I've setup MDS, installed the sim
2. Ran 2 simulators using sim1 and sim2.bat.
3. Added sim2 and a contact to sim1's BBM,
4. In Eclipse went to debug, dug configurations, Blackberry simulator, advanced. 
    
   Added this as my Customized command line:

   ```
   "C:\Users\Adminy\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\
   BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 7.0.0\7.0.0.236 (9900)\
   fledge.exe" /app=Jvm.dll /handheld=9900 /session=Sim1
   /app-param=JvmAlxConfigFile:9900.xml /data-port=0x4d44
   /data-port=0x4d4e /pin=0x2100000A /app-param=regVersion=3
   /app-param=regDestIP=127.0.0.1 /app-param=regDestPort=19781
   /app-param=regSrcPort=19783 /app-param=DisableSyncServiceRecord
   ```

This as my customized working dir:

```
C:\Users\Casey\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\
BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 7.0.0\7.0.0.236 (9900)
```

And this as my customized MDS directory:

```
C:\bbmsdk\MDS Simulator\mds
```

But when I try to debug the sample apps they're not showing up on the simulator. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer so this can be closed. I had to load the .cod in the simulator.